# Sequelize bulkCreate not including newly added columns

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm having difficulty understanding why bulkCreate will not include my two newly created columns, perhaps it's the migration?

My new migration is as follows:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    queryInterface.addColumn('users', 'brand_id', {
      allowNull: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: null,
    });

    queryInterface.addColumn('users', 'store_id', {
      allowNull: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: null,
    });    

    return true;
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'brand_id');
    queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'store_id');
    return true;
  }
};
```

I have a helper function for creating multiple users for the purpose of testing that looks something like this:

```
const properties = { brand_id: 123 };
const user = [];
users.push(Object.assign({}, {
  name: chance.last(),
  email: chance.email(),
  password,
  access_key: uuid(),
}, properties));

const newUsers = await models.user.bulkCreate(users, { returning: true, logging: console.log });
```

The output of the logging is:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("id","name","email","password","access_key","created_at","updated_at") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Valente','letubdo@iwefa.fm','$2a$08$B5riQzA82ChwuH1q8HpGxOBK2uQj2m.BiHcEjytiox5yD.8u1fT5W','e62bf96c-0117-490f-9c80-b60e406238b0','2018-09-25 18:30:04.666 +00:00','2018-09-25 18:30:04.666 +00:00') RETURNING *;
```

You'll see that brand_id is completely ignored in the query, even if I change the following:

```
users.push(Object.assign({}, {
  name: chance.last(),
  email: chance.email(),
  password,
  access_key: uuid(),
  brand_id: 123,
}, properties));
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you add these columns to the model?

Comment: Please show the model code `User`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did not add the two new columns to the user model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    name: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    email: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    access_key: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    brand_id: {
      allowNull: true,
      true: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    store_id: {
      allowNull: true,
      true: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    }    
  }, {
    underscored: true,
  });
  return user;
};
```